# What is the probability of getting exactly one pair in poker?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, combinations, poker

Problem:

What is the probability of getting exactly one pair in poker?

Answer:

Let $p$ be the  probability we seek.
\begin{align*}
p &= \dfrac{ 13  {{4} \choose {2}} (48)(44)(40)}{ {{52} \choose {5}} } \\
{4} \choose {2} &= \dfrac{ 4(3) }{ 2} = 6 \\
{52} \choose {5} &= \dfrac{ 52(51)(50)(49)(48) }{ 5(4)(3)(2) } \\
{52} \choose {5} &= \dfrac{ 52(51)(5)(49)(48) }{ 4(3) } \\
{52} \choose {5} &= 52(51)(5)(49)(4) \\
\end{align*}
\begin{align*}
p &= \dfrac{  13(6)(48)(44)(40) }{  52(51)(5)(49)(4)  } \\
p &= \dfrac{  6(48)(44)(40) }{  4(51)(5)(49)(4)  } \\
p &= \dfrac{  3(48)(44)(40) }{  2(51)(5)(49)(4)  } \\
p &= \dfrac{  3(48)(44)(10) }{  2(51)(5)(49)  } \\
p &= \dfrac{  48(44)(10) }{  2(17)(5)(49)  } \\
p &= \dfrac{  48(44)(2) }{  2(17)(49)  } \\
p &= \dfrac{  48(22)(2) }{  17(49)  } \\
p &= \dfrac{  2112 }{ 833  } \\
p &\doteq fixme
\end{align*}
I believe the correct answer is: $ .422569 $.
I suspect this line is wrong:
$$ p = \dfrac{ 13  {{4} \choose {2}} (48)(44)(40)}{ {{52} \choose {5}} } $$
Here is why I think it is right. The first term, $13$ is there because there are
$13$ different ranks you can have. The next term is there because to have a pair, you select two cards of the same rank from four cards. Now for the last
three terms of the numerator. After selecting two of the same rank, such as a pair
of aces, there are $48$ cards left to be selected. After selecting another card,
such as a jack there are $44$ cards left to be selected.

In terms of the denominator, it is there because a poker hand is $5$ cards from
a deck of $52$ cards.

Where did I go wrong?

Comment: A partial alternative to the remedy provided by the answer of N.F.Taussig, is to comprehend why the first sentence in his answer is accurate.  Then, you simply apply the $~\dfrac{1}{3!}~$ scalar to the computation that you have already done.

Comment: People sometimes feel it's hard to know when order "matters" and when it doesn't. It's perhaps worthwhile to mention here that **you** decided that order doesn't matter when you wrote $\binom{52}5$ in the denominator. It's OK (even if somewhat roundabout) to count the ordered tuples of cards dealt to the players if you do it consistently. What you can't do is count unordered tuples in the denominator and ordered tuples (or in this case a mixture of ordered and unordered) in the numerator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You counted each hand $3!$ times, because the order in which the three singletons are selected does not matter.  For instance, if your hand is
$$5\clubsuit, \color{red}{5\diamondsuit}, \color{red}{8\diamondsuit}, \color{red}{9\heartsuit}, J\spadesuit$$
it does not matter whether you first select $\color{red}{8\diamondsuit}$, then $\color{red}{9\heartsuit}$, then $J\spadesuit$, or first select $J\spadesuit$, then $\color{red}{8\diamondsuit}$, and then $\color{red}{9\heartsuit}$.

There are $13$ ways to select the rank of the pair and $\binom{4}{2}$ ways to select two cards of that rank.  There are $\binom{12}{3}$ ways to select three ranks from which one card each will be drawn and $4$ ways to select a card from each of those ranks.  Since there are $\binom{52}{5}$ possible five-card hands, the probability of selecting exactly one pair is
$$\frac{\dbinom{13}{1}\dbinom{4}{2}\dbinom{12}{3}\dbinom{4}{1}\dbinom{4}{1}\dbinom{4}{1}}{\dbinom{52}{5}}$$